# C++ - Send messages between processes

Tags: c++, struct, printing

I have some processes connected via pipes, so stdout from one is the stdin for the other one, and viceversa. I need to pass this `struct Message` via stdin and stdout, but I can't manage to do it.

The struct:

```
strcut Task{
  bool some;
  char text[MAX_TEXT_AREA];
}

struct Stat{
  char text[MAX_TEXT_AREA];
  unsigned short id;
}

struct Message{
  int nTasks;
  int nStats;
  Task tasks[];
  Stat stats[];
}
```

This is what i've tried in order to put the `Message` to stdout:

```
Message* m; //suppose it's initialized
write(STDOUT_FILENO, m, sizeof(Message));
for(int i=0; i<m->nTasks; ++i) write(STDOUT_FILENO, m->tasks[i], sizeof(Task));
for(int i=0; i<m->nStats; ++i) write(STDOUT_FILENO, m->stats[i], sizeof(Stat));
```

I get some compilation errors but I've no idea how to solve this. Is there a way to print the message without modifying any `struct`?

For reading this is what I've got:

```
Message* m;
while(read(STDIN_FILENO, m, sizeof(Message))){
  m->tasks = new Tarea[m->nTasks];
  m->stats = new Stat[m->nStats];
  for(int i=0; i<m->nTasks; ++i){
    m->tasks[i] = new Task;
    read(0, m->tasks[i], sizeof(Task));
  }for(int i=0; i<m->nStats; ++i){
    m->stats[i] = new Stat;
    read(0, m->stats[i], sizeof(Stat));
  }
}
```

One process creates the message and prints it, then the other process reads it, modifies it, and prints it again to the first process (like a ring), and so on.

Again, I need this to `write/read` without modifying any `struct`. Thanks.

Comment: A pipe carries a stream of bytes. So start by specifying the format for the bytes that will be exchanged between the processes. This is not something you can code before you specify it unless you have significant experience and expertise in this area. Protocols should be documented before they're implemented.

Comment: I just have defined two pipes, used the `dup2` so stdin and stdout are redirected, and that's it. How should be that protocol defined? This is why I'm asking, because I have no experience in this.

Comment: @sant016 Lookup about _data de-/serialization_, and support from appropriate libraries.

Comment: Note that although you may send messages of N bytes, you will not necessarily receive N bytes on your first read at the receiving end, so **you need to read in a loop** and accumulate the bytes read until you have enough for a message.

Comment: @MarkSetchell so you're saying the loop I have while reading is bad?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. You assume that your read returns a whole message and then use the elements within the Message struct on the very next line, when you may only have filled the first couple of bytes of the Message struct. You need to read in a loop till you have received an entire message.

Comment: @MarkSetchell but how do I know when to stop the loop? How to know the message is sent entirely?

Comment: Each `read()` tells you, as its return value, how many bytes it read so you keep reading until you have accumulated `sizeof(Message)` bytes making sure you move your read pointer alomg by however many bytes you have got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are due to bad calls to `read`/`write`, for example you wrote:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, m->tasks[i], sizeof(Task));
```

but 2nd args of write should be an address, while `task[i]` is a `Task` not the address of. So change to:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, m->tasks+i, sizeof(Task));
```

or

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(m->tasks[i]), sizeof(Task));
```

Same remark for `read`.

Don't worry about "protocols", since you are using local communications between processes, on the same machine, written in the same language, everything is ok until...

----EDIT----

But you need to send (at least) the number of of tasks and stats, doing:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, m, sizeof(Message))
```

is wrong, because it is not sufficient to determine the size of the arrays at the other end. You need to send them:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, m->nTasks, sizeof(m->nTasks));
write(STDOUT_FILENO, m->nStats, sizeof(m->nStats));
```

and read them accordingly.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why this is bad advice. Even on the same machine, you still need to specify the format of the data. Otherwise when it doesn't work, it's literally impossible to know which end is at fault. Also, there's still no guarantee the other side will be able to make sense of the data for many reasons including that the data may not have a fixed size, such as his `Message` struct.

Comment: You're right, he didn't sent the numbers of tasks and stats.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Umm.. Until...?

Comment: Until you decide to change either the languages on both ends or communicate across machines. Then you'll need to define a proper (de)serialization.

Comment: Is it enough for sending `Stat` and `Task` too? Don't I have to send each attribute of each `struct`?

Comment: No they are embedded...that's why structures are for.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès do I really have to read until all bytes of `Message` have been read? should I do that before passing `nTasks` and `nStats`?

Comment: Either send `Message` (with its unuseful parts) or `nTasks` `nStats` separately before sending the arrays.